# Issue running PowerShell Commands from batch or .cmd file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to update the DNS IP on all DR Servers and I tried changing the DNS IP using the below script and it is not working through batch file or .cmd file

Please help

```
PowerShell -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -command Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList '-noprofile', '-command', &{(Get-DnsClientServerAddress | where {$_.ServerAddresses -contains 192.168.5.15} | Set-DnsClientServerAddress -ServerAddresses 192.168.15.100,192.168.15.101) -Verbose -Confirm:$false; ipconfig /flushdns; ipconfig /flushdns; Clear-DnsClientCache; Register-DnsClient -verb RunAs}
```

I am getting error as below

```
Missing expression after ',' in pipeline element.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpression

'{' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PowerShell -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -command "& {(Get-DnsClientServerAddress | where {$_.ServerAddresses -contains "192.168.5.15"} | Set-DnsClientServerAddress -ServerAddresses "192.168.15.100","192.168.15.101") ; ipconfig /flushdns; ipconfig /flushdns; Clear-DnsClientCache; Register-DnsClient -verb RunAs}"
```

You were having punctuation errors like not enclosing script in quotes. Also i have removed unnecessary Start-Process.

Comment: I am getting the below error, I want run this from .bat or .cmd file

At line:1 char:162
+ ... ess -ServerAddresses 192.168.15.100,192.168.15.101)  ipconfig /flushd ...
+                                                          ~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'ipconfig' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken